# VBA / Userforms Excel

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Not really sure how to search for what I am needing,  New to VBA and Userform.

I have many boxes in my form,   with two,, combobox's, ones list is dependend on the selection of the first

Say Combobox A options are:   "On", "Off", "Locked", and "Pending".
With Combobox B, If ComboBox A is selected as "Pending", then the options may be "Damaged", "New" or "Added",  all other options in Combobox A would cause B to simply show "OPTIONAL". (not actual combobox list's, just fictional options for simplified question)

I have managed to get it to work, in sorts,  it works, based on the status of ComboBox A at time form is loaded.  However, If I change the Status of Combobox A  I have to save and exit / reload the form in order for Box B to see the change and updated based on my If then Else statement.

Can someone direct me to what I need to search for?  The terminology used? or some direction?

Thanks in advance.
Tom

Comment: *Can someone direct me to what I need to search for?* - Why not just ask how to do it without reloading the form? You've already described what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the "Change" event of the combobox A. Here is how you can adjust the combo B without reloading the form:

```
Private Sub ComboA_Change()
    ComboB.Clear 
    If ComboA.Text = "Pending" Then
        ComboB.AddItem ("Damaged") 
        ComboB.AddItem ("New") 
        ComboB.AddItem ("Added") 
    Else
        ComboB.Text = "Optional" 
    Endif
End Sub
```